# HSSFCell - determining what type of numeric

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using Apache POI, I am trying to process a large amount of numeric data. I am checking for the cell type, for instance

```
     case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                value = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
```

Is there a way I can determine what type of numeric value the cell holds? For instance, how do I know that it is safe to cast the return value to a non-floating point value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getNumericCellValue](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getNumericCellValue()) returns double for all the numeric cells. You can check values like this:

```
if( Math.floor(d) == d ) {
...
}
```